# Remove Javascript Variables from Typescript Debugger in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I'm debugging Typescript in VS Code a lot of variables from the generated javascript show up, such as `_a` or `_i` in the "variables" section. Is there a way to get rid of them, so I only see variables declared in the Typescript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get rid of them, so I only see variables declared in the Typescript file?

No. TypeScript sourcemaps do not support variable name mapping yet.